# Unable to traverse xml file in mxgraph to get specifing attribute value of child node?

Tags: javascript, xml, mxgraph

I am trying to traverse a XML file.Based on the values in the xml file, I want to update another XML file. I want to get "mxcell" value and its attribute.I have tried to parse the xml using mxutil.parseXml() and retrieve the child node in the following way.I am getting the value of x as nodelist[body], where body is giving parser error.

Code to traverse xml

```
var xmldoc = mxUtils.parseXml(nodes);
var x = xmldoc.documentElement.childNodes;
```

XML file nodes

```
<mxGraphModel>
<root>
<mxCell id="0"/>
<mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
<mxCell id="Kn0cXeNcbUv7v0NK2pj5-1" value="" style="shape=mxgraph.bpmn.shape;html=1;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;labelBackgroundColor=#ffffff;verticalAlign=top;align=center;perimeter=ellipsePerimeter;outlineConnect=0;outline=standard;symbol=general;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell><mxCell id="Kn0cXeNcbUv7v0NK2pj5-2" value="" style="shape=mxgraph.bpmn.shape;html=1;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;labelBackgroundColor=#ffffff;verticalAlign=top;align=center;perimeter=ellipsePerimeter;outlineConnect=0;outline=throwing;symbol=general;" vertex="1" parent="1"><mxGeometry x="20" y="90" width="50" height="50" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
</root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

I want to retrieve the value of each "mxcell" style attribute in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parse error is due to the fact that you are passing the nodes directly to the 'mxUtils.parseXml' method. The [documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxUtils-js.html#mxUtils.parseXml) states that you should be passing a string as parameter.

Having that into account, you can provide your xml as string:

```
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(
    '<mxGraphModel>' + 
        '<root>' + 
            '<mxCell id="0"/>' + 
            '<mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>' + 
            '<mxCell id="Kn0cXeNcbUv7v0NK2pj5-1" value="" style="shape=mxgraph.bpmn.shape;html=1;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;labelBackgroundColor=#ffffff;verticalAlign=top;align=center;perimeter=ellipsePerimeter;outlineConnect=0;outline=standard;symbol=general;" vertex="1" parent="1">' + 
                '<mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" as="geometry"/>' + 
            '</mxCell>' + 
            '<mxCell id="Kn0cXeNcbUv7v0NK2pj5-2" value="" style="shape=mxgraph.bpmn.shape;html=1;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;labelBackgroundColor=#ffffff;verticalAlign=top;align=center;perimeter=ellipsePerimeter;outlineConnect=0;outline=throwing;symbol=general;" vertex="1" parent="1">' + 
                '<mxGeometry x="20" y="90" width="50" height="50" as="geometry"/>' + 
            '</mxCell>' + 
        '</root>' + 
    '</mxGraphModel>'
);
```

And then you can get the style of the `mxCell` tags. I am generating an object with the id of the `mxCell` as key and the `style` attribute as value:

```
var data = {};
doc.querySelectorAll('mxcell').forEach(function(node) {
    data[node.id] = node.getAttribute('style');
});
```

Comment: But my nodes keep changing.. every time node is changes it is registered in nodes variable

Comment: @Prateeknaik, and how does it change? Where do you get this `nodes` variable from?

Comment: It changes to add new mxcell node to the file or removes one of the created mxcell... For eg.. i am getting my nodes value by using mxutils.getXml.getModel() whenever a shape is created on canvas ... So if new shape is created it gets registered in that variable

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code in your question? Where is the XML? Is it in the DOM?

Comment: ' var enc = new mxCodec();
        var xml = enc.encode(b.getModel());
        nodess = mxUtils.getXml(xml)
        console.log(nodess); '

Comment: this the code which is giving me the xml file from the canvas.. where b hold the graph. i want to traverse this file to get list of "mxcells" style attribute

Comment: It seems that you already have the xml through the call to `mxUtils.getXml`, so I would say you don't have to parse it (by calling `mxUtils.parseXml`). Maybe you can directly apply the second script in my answer to `nodes`?